# Use of super and how to replace it, Java

Tags: java, super

My question is about if there is a way to replace super to still call a parent method or a parent variable?

If there is way, is it similar to the use of super?

In quick words, is super replaceable?

Comment: Replace it why?

Comment: Maybe you should explain what you want to do?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What are you actually trying to do, and why do you think replacing the `super` keyword will accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some languages do not implement the concept of subclassing (like Visual Basic, in earlier versions). A workaround to call "superclass methods" was to implement the delegate pattern, and instanciate the "superclass" (which was no real superclass) there. Then, the superclass was not invoked via the keyword `super`, but via the delegation pattern. To understand the delegate pattern, see Design Pattern literature - or just https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

This concept describes how `super` could be replaced by delegation - but there is no need to do so in Java. Simply don't do it.

And yes, there is a difference: When you instanciate a java object, you have this object instance, that provides all methods etc from its superclasses. When you implement the workaround with a delegate pattern, you have a second instance (the superclass-delegate would be a separate instance in this case).